# Make column fill vertical space in Bulma?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have the following simple layout (with the exception that the `textarea` becomes a Code  Mirror at runtime):

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-paddingless" style="background: indigo;">
            <textarea id="code-editor"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is - the first column does not fill the vertical space of the page (below the tabs) - rather it just wraps the height of the `textarea`. For instance:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to make the column fill the page?

Comment: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/860 This github issue may help

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox should work for you! For your reference I love this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Setting up your `.columns` like this should do the trick:

```
.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; // this is default
    align-items: stretch; // this will stretch the children vertically
}
```

Unsure how you have `.column` styled (ie height: 100%) but let me know if this does NOT work and I can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Can you share the styles associated with your columns, column, and is-paddingless classes?

Answer (score 0):

Give a class or id or just write inline style and do

```
 min-height : XXvh;
```

Where xx is how VH you need.

According to [MOzila devaloper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) 
vh
Equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.

---

Comment: Unless the second column is a fixed height and even then it would be better to have the first column fill the space rather then hardcode a size